# How to calculate closest distance between two AABBs (vector form)?

Tags: distance, bounding-box, closest, aabb

How to calculate closest distance between two AABBs (vector form)? I found a solution [here](https://bitbucket.org/kaba2/pastel/src/c2bbbc82555e04ba91e61a0795ab4acfae85527c/pastel/geometry/distance/distance_alignedbox_alignedbox.hpp?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). Is it possible extract a vector form of this? I know a vector form of AABB - point distance.

Candidate:

```cpp
Float distance(const Box & a, const Box & b) {
    return Vector::zero.max(a.min - b.max).max(b.min - a.max).magnitude();
}
```

Comment: In which language? What did you already try?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

The distance between two axis-aligned bounding boxes (AABB) can be computed as follows:

1. Find the intersection box of two input boxes, which can be expressed in C++:

```
Box Box::intersection( const Box & b ) const
{
    Box res;
    for ( int i = 0; i < V::elements; ++i )
    {
        res.min[i] = std::max( min[i], b.min[i] );
        res.max[i] = std::min( max[i], b.max[i] );
    }
    return res;
}
```

where `min` and `max` are two corner points of a box.

2. Then the squared distance between two boxes is:

```
T Box::getDistanceSq( const Box & b ) const
{
    auto ibox = intersection( b );
    T distSq = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < V::elements; ++i )
        if ( ibox.min[i] > ibox.max[i] )
            distSq += sqr( ibox.min[i] - ibox.max[i] );
    return distSq;
}
```

The function returns zero if input boxes touch or intersect.

The code above was taken from [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#readme) and it works both for 2D (`V::elements=2`) and 3D (`V::elements=3`).

It is not quite clear what you mean by "vector form", since the distance is a scalar. If one wants a more concise implementation of `getDistanceSq`, then in addition to `intersection` the second part of the function can be named somehow.